# basic java I/O text replacing, not getting expected output

Tags: java, io

i have a text file with database table data in it and im trying to delete a part of the table. this is what is in the file:

```
name= john
name= bill
name= tom
name= bob
name= mike
```

here is my java code that compiles and runs, but the output is not what i expected and stuck.

```
import java.io.*;
public class FileUtil {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream("\\test.txt");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fStream));


            while (in.ready()) {
                //System.out.println(in.readLine());
                String line = in.readLine();
                String keyword = "name="; //keyword to delete in txt file
                String newLine=line.replaceAll(keyword,""); //delete lines that say name=
                BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("testEdited.txt"));
                out.write(newLine.getBytes());
                out.close();

            }
            in.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File input error");
        }

    }
}
```

the output in the testEdited file is this:

mike

obviously i want to be left with just the 5 names. Can anyone help me out?
thanks

Comment: Your `new FileOutputStream` will always write the data from the beginning of the file. Consider using the other constructor that takes `append` as a boolean parameter. Or open it once at the top and close it once at the end of your program. Oh, is this homework?

Comment: no, im creating this program to assist with a data mining project for a different class, i need to remove un-needed table data and trying to brush up on my java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("testEdited.txt",true));
```

`true` will append data to your file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
        String line;
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("testEdited.txt"));

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String newLine=line.replaceAll("name=","");
            out.write(newLine.getBytes());
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
```

No need to keep opening and closing your output file.

Also regarding the "name=" declaration, there's not much point in assigning to to a variable and only using it on the line immediately following it. If it needs to be a shared constant, declare it as `(private|public) static final String foo = "bar";` in a class somewhere.

Additionally, there's not much benefit to wrapping a file output stream (or file writer) in the appropriate buffered version, the operating system will buffer writes for you automatically, and it does a good job at this.

You should also replace your streams with readers and close your files in finally blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `BufferedInputStream/BufferedOutputStream` for parallel readwrite operations.
Please use `RandomAccessFile` if you want to read and write to the file at the same time.

Comment: The dest file is different than the source.